# Removing duplicates fromarray of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, arraylist

I have an array of objects as myData which consists of the below JSON structure:

```
const data = {
    myData: [
        { Type: 'REAL', Tenure: '12', Name: 'WEBPAGE' },
        { Type: 'REAL', Tenure: '24', Name: 'SERVER' },
        { Type: 'REAL', Tenure: '12', Name: 'WEBPAGE' },
    ],
};
```

I want to get rid of duplicate entries by keeping performance in mind as this array could be of length 1000+ using Javascript.

The Expected Output that I am looking for is as follow since myData[0] && myData[2] are duplicate here:

```
const result = {
    myData: [
        { Type: 'REAL', Tenure: '24', Name: 'SERVER' },
        { Type: 'REAL', Tenure: '12', Name: 'WEBPAGE' },
    ],
};
```

Comment: First of all, How do you consider that two objects are duplicates? Are you matching all properties or just specific property?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Lodash uniq function for more information please check https://lodash.com/docs/3.10.1#uniq